# How can I access responseText of a jqXHR object from a successfull AJAX call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cross-domain, xmlhttprequest

I have following ajax call in my JavaScript code

```
url = 'http://news.ycombinator.com/?callback=?';
$.ajax({url:url ,async:!1,dataType:'script', complete:function(result)
                                   {alert(JSON.stringify(result));} 
      });
```

Following is printed out in alert.

```
{'readyState':4, status:200, statusText:'success'}
```

It doesn't have responseText.But still, in the chrome console I can see all of the return HTML data of ycombinator page.How can I access this text?

On the other hand if I change the url variable to a url which returns a valid json object like following,

```
urll = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=basshunter&format=5&max-results=5&v=2&alt=jsonc';
$.ajax({url:urll ,async:!1, complete:function(result)
                                   {alert(JSON.stringify(result));} 
      });
```

this returns all of the responseText as expected.

One thing to note is if I don't point the url to a valid JSON returning url as in first case, I have to provide option dataType:'script'(or JSON).Otherwise it will throw a cross-domain request error.In second case it didn't throw any cross-domain error even if I didn't specify dataType.

Comment: `responseText` is probably inherited from the objects prototype. Try `alert(result.responseText)`

Comment: Seems to work http://jsfiddle.net/X7WAj/

Comment: yeah, it's working in case of gdata url, it has a valid json object in it's body.But not with the first ycombinator url

Comment: The first case doesn't work because it doesn't allow cross domain ajax calls.

Comment: but, cross domain calls can be made for script and jsonp types.So it does work in fetching the content, which can be observed in Chrome console.And it throws a format error in data.But my problem is, I can't access it in the function call

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4325/discussion-between-tetaxa-and-sravan)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your **complete** callback with **success**. **Success** callback executed when ajax request completed successfully.

Also in your dataType use "json" instead of "script"
if you use "script" in **dataType** it will return like `"{\"key\":\"value\"}".`

if you use "json" in **dataType** it will return like `{"key":"value"}.`

Comment: yeah I tried with Success initially, it will not show the alert box at all!!But again, I can still see the data in console.